# How to change text color with a button in java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Im working on NetBeans and i want to change the color of my texts and change my images when i click on buttons, the blue button changes to blue, the red to red etc.
Im doing:

```
    EscolherCor.setTextColor(0,0,0);
```

Is there any code i can use to solve this?

Comment: Your answer is somewhere in this site. Try to search **change text color in java** . And please try to ask a genuin question.

Comment: What does [How to use buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and the [JavaDocs for `JButton`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html) tell you? (Hint, they will tell you that `setTextColor` does not exist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways you can achieve this:

Only to a font:

```
JLabel EscolherCor= new JLabel ("Color");
EscolherCor.setForeground(Color.red);
```

Using Hex value:

```
JLabel EscolherCor= new JLabel ("Color");
Color color = Color.decode("#43B7BA");
EscolherCor.setForeground(color);
```

Using RGB:

```
JLabel EscolherCor= new JLabel ("Color");
Color color = new Color(255,0,0);
EscolherCor.setForeground(color);
```

Using html:

```
JLabel EscolherCor = new JLabel("<html>label <font color='blue'>blue-color</font></html>");
```

To the background:

```
JLabel EscolherCor= new JLabel ("Color");
EscolherCor.setBackground(Color.red);
```

Comment: I think the new JLabel is evitable if you put:
import java.awt.Color;

Comment: So where are you going to put that color? I mean what text?

Comment: I am putting it in a lot of texts i already done it ( but had to wrote a bit )